# how to remotely copy file to a remote linux machine and restart service afterward?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos, scripting

I would like to copy files using SCP to a remote Linux machine.

I will regularly update hosts and dnsmasq.conf and use SCP to copy them to the remote machine:
/etc/hosts
/etc/dnsmasq.conf

right after I will need to run:
"sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq"

I don't want the remote user to do anything on the remote machine but what I just mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: SCP: `scp user1@host1:/path/to/origin user2@host2:/path/to/target` (user@host: can be skipped for local_user@localhost) ; combining commands: run command 2 if command 1 succeeded: `command 1 && command 2`.  Running commands remotely with ssh: `ssh user@host "command"` (or use hard quotes) - Will that do for you? Do you need to enter passwords for either login or the `sudo`?

Comment: I will need to add Password as well.

Comment: For the `sudo`, or for the `ssh`?  Can you use an SSH certificate to log in?  Can you afford your passwords to be in plain text?

Comment: I can use certificate. right. How can I limit the access though?

Comment: Then I would suggest using certificates for (passwordless) logins and specifically allowing the respective sudo command in the sudoers file as passwordless.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restart the service whenever the files are modified (no matter by whom), you might consider using [`incron`](https://github.com/ar-/incron) on the remote machine.

Just install the package and set the proper `incrontab` entry:

```
/etc/dnsmasq.conf IN_MODIFY systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

I am using it e.g. to trigger a `createrepo` command when I upload an rpm package to my local repository, and it seems to work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the advice of @Fiximan, you can use the following command to accomplish what you need.

```
ssh -o "PermitLocalCommand yes" -o "LocalCommand sleep 10 && sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq" user2@host2 "scp user1@host1:/path/to/source /path/to/target"
```

This will run `scp` to copy the local file onto the remote system; at the same time, it will wait 10 seconds, and then shutdown the local system.  Unfortunately, this shuts down after 10 seconds, whether or not the `scp` was successful.

If your system is new enough, it might support using an exclamation mark to run the commands locally (provided PermitLocalCommand is enabled).  In this case, rather than using `-o "LocalCommand sleep 10 && sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq"`, you can instead run

```
ssh -o "PermitLocalCommand yes" user2@host2 "scp user1@host1:/path/to/source /path/to/target && !sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq"
```

The exclamation mark sends the command to be executed on the local system.  In this case, the local system is shut down only if the `scp` is successful, and the system would ask for whatever passwords that are missing.

If you would like the local system to be shut down regardless of whether `scp` is successful, you can replace `&&` with `;`.